# Not sure how to implement the standard deviation through recursion

Tags: scala, functional-programming

So I have the generic method set up consisting of:

- A parameter of type T
- A List of T's (which will be the data set that I will be looking at)
- A function from T to double (This function will be used to take a property from each data element. So 
  basically the property is used to compute the and return standard deviation.)
  For example the List(7.63, 3.87, 1.59, 8.26, 5.11, 0.65, 7.88) should return 3.100496888

That last bullet is confusing me and I'm not sure how to put it in the form of recursion.

````
```
  def standardDeviation[T](elements: List[T], property: T => Double): Double = {

  }
```
````

Sorry for my lack of experience. Functional programming is just not my strong spot.

Comment: You should not need to use recursion; a sequence of calls to `map`, `sum`,  and `length` should do it.

Comment: Really because I’m restricted from using any form of state change (eg use of “var”)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to change the signature you would have to use local function and make that function tail-recursive

```
def standardDeviation[T](elements: List[T], property: T => Double): Double = {
  val values = elements.map(property)
  val size = elements.size.toDouble
  // this could acually be replaced by values.sum
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def calculateSum(remaining: List[Double], acc: Double): Double = remaining match {
    case head :: tail => calculateSum(tail, acc + head)
    case Nil          => acc
  }
  val mean = calculateSum(values, 0.0) / size
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def calculateSumOfDiffs(remaining: List[Double], acc: Double): Double = remaining match {
    case head :: tail => calculateSumOfDiffs(tail, acc + Math.pow(head - mean, 2.0))
    case Nil          => acc
  }
  Math.sqrt(calculateSumOfDiffs(values, 0.0) / (size - 1))
}
```

When you are doing tail recursive  computation you have to somehow pass results-so-far, so if you cannot expose the intermediate results in API, this is the only way.

However, you don't have to implement this using tail rec, but instead use some functional approach instead:

```
def standardDeviation[T](elements: List[T], property: T => Double): Double = {
  val values = elements.map(property)
  val size = values.size.toDouble
  val mean = values.sum / size
  Math.sqrt(values.map(x => Math.pow(x - mean, 2.0)).sum / (size - 1))
}
```

Comment: The first solution kinda-reimplements `fold` two times. The second one produces unnecessary intermediate lists. It would probably be nice to demonstrate a shorter solution that takes constant extra space.

Comment: Regarding first - user asked how he could use tailrec, so I showed him how before I moved on to showing why he doesn't need it. Regarding second example, 
yes, you could create a `view` on values, but I would be very careful about messing with peoples heads about optimizations if they haven't understood the basics. That's how you get cargo cultists.

Comment: It's less about optimizations, more about the signature not making any sense if one uses `elements.map`. If `O(n)` overhead would not be a problem, then one could skip all the generics, and pass an `elements: List[Double]` directly. Without a careful `O(1)`-space overhead solution inside of the method, this signature loses its raison d'être. With the generics, the signature literally screams _"please don't map over the elements, just give me the list and the statistic that you want to compute the standard deviation for, I'll take care of the rest"_.

Comment: It is either about O(1) extra memory or about avoiding recomputing `property` for each element twice. Author didn't specify their preferences so I made a choice towards less recomputation.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need recursion. This could be computed using foldLeft:

```
elements.foldLeft(0) {
   case (accumulator, item) => ...//calculate here next value from previously calculated 
                                  //value (accumulator) and current item
}
```